# How to call ASP MVC CSHTML View directly with ".cshtml" extension from browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to call my asp mvc CSHTML View directly from browser with ".cshtml" extension like:

```
    www.mysite.com\receive.cshtml?...
```

instead

```
    www.mysite.com\receive?...
```

but i got 404

any idea ?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this. What about the M and C in MVC?!? No Model? No controller? What is this world going to?! All is lost.

Comment: The question is quite valid. There are a lot of reasons to do this. I'm finding everyday that the MVC model is not the best thing and actually gets in the way a lot while developing modern applications, where the logic is 100% in the client. In those cases, controllers and actions become just boilerplate I need to return HTML, always having empty actions with "return View()". And while you can just use plain HTML files, some pieces of view logic like razor helpers are welcome in views, and be able to use those shouldn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** By default `IIS Request Filtering` is configured not to serve requests to `.cshtml` files.

**2.** Razor views are not meant to be accessed directly by the client. yet, take a look at https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars

Comment: so may i do something like route or ... to redirect `www.mysite.com\receive.cshtml?...` to `www.mysite.com\receive?...`

Comment: You can create a generic `action` that will load and render a `view` based on a view-name you pass to it. you'll also have to create another `route` that would match that generic action and passing it the view-name.

Comment: following [haim770](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1625737/haim770) explains,
i added this code to my project "RouteConfig.cs" file and it's done

        `routes.MapRoute(
            "MyRouteName",
            "Receive.cshtml/{param1}/{param2}/{...}",
            new { controller = "Receive", action = "Index"
            , param1 = UrlParameter.Optional
            , param1 = UrlParameter.Optional
            , ...    = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`